On call payments
I've been asked for a price for on-call payments as they require me to be available. This would be a Friday from 2100-1300 on Saturday, immediate response required. If there was an issue I'd need time later on the Saturday and possibly Sunday to fix. So I cant make plans nearly all weekend. It's 4 times a year unless the other site had issues and would be asked for those weekends too. The role is very specialised engineer and we have noone else at the site (only a couple in the country) that can do it other than me until we hire a second person. I'm wondering where the price point should be. (Salary to give idea is ~80)
Many thanks

This seems like a reasonable question, but I also suspect there's a huge variance in real-world answers. At my previous employers, oncall was more frequent than 4 weekends a year, and the additional salary was zero — it was just a built-in responsibility. I'm at a point in my life where time is often more valuable than money, so I would personally "bill" it in terms of free PTO: one day for the Friday - Saturday, plus another day per half-day that I actually need to work. YMMV, of course.

We need more information - Is your work type remote or would it be onsite.  We also need a country (as there may be cultural and legal differences that affect the answer)

Thanks for the quick responses. It UK. At present I'm on call one week in two but the payment wasn't really set up correctly. We used to work shift so received a shift allowance and we went to on call for better coverage as it's 2 people covering 18hrs the sites open. We are remote but would have to answer the phone immediately and come to site if needed. Time is more valuable and I take a lot of toil but being on my own this won't be possible for a while.

@PaulHarmer [Edit] your question.  It's currently closed.  Be sure you remove asking us for advice and focus on the actual question you want answered. I wouldn't say being on call 4 times a year is a toil or even a burden.

This seems like a reasonable ask. A lot of this comes down to the details:

How often do you expect to be called? Is this emergency back stop that is only required once every 5 years or do you expect 3 calls pers shift?
How do you typically spend your weekends during this time. Would "being on call" be disruptive or just a minor inconvenience?
What exactly does "immediate response" mean. For example, would you be able to go grocery shopping if you are on call? ("I call you back in 15" or "I'll be on site in half an hour").

One approach is to treat the on-call the same as being on-shift. You can't do anything else and you need to be responsive. In this is case, it's the same as overtime and it might be good to check overtime rules and compensation policies for your company. This is still a good deal for you, since in some cases you will get paid to sleep. Time and a half or 2x seems like a decent starting point.
If it's less arduous than a full shift you can certainly tone it down a bit. If being on call are not particularly disruptive for you and calls are rare, you can step down to regular salary or even half salary. In this the solution suggested by DavidT sounds like a good option: Go half salary for being on call and full salary for all hours actually worked.
If the company really needs this and you are one of the few people that can do it, you have a quite a bit of leverage. But using this lever too aggressively is not going to make you any friends. You may gain short term money at the expense of long term career outlook (which may or may not matter to you).
If you want to avoid negotiating money, another option would be to ask for compensation time or a extra vacation days instead. Its just another tool to handle this type of thing and the more  flexible you are the more likely it is to end up with a solution that both parties are happy with.

Most of my work is contract work  $.../hour, so I have a standard rate I quote most clients.
For on call time, I quote 50% of my standard hourly rate + an additional 50% if I am actually called, so basically one of two things happens:

I am not called in which case I make 1/2 of my usual rate.
I am called in which case I am just billing my standard rate - for the time I am working, once I am done I go back to the on-call rate.

The reason for the double rate is that it creates an incentive not to call me for trivial stuff / stuff that can wait.
I think you said your salary is 80K, so reasonable numbers using this strategy might be 50/hour on call and 100/hour if called.
Alternatively, if you value vacation time more than money you could do: 1 hour of vacation for every hour of on call and 2 hours of vacation if you are actually called.


I've been asked for a price for on-call payments as they require me to be available. This would be a Friday from 2100-1300 on Saturday, immediate response required.

These on-call ideas often proceed from completely unrealistic assumptions about the reliability of one person's availability and response.
People fall sick suddenly with diarrhea or crippling stomach pain. Heart attacks put them in hospital. Their cars don't start, or they crash on the way to work. The internet breaks down, at home or at work. Their mobile phone is in a dead spot. There's often a lack of imagination, or a failure to integrate experience, about how large this space is and how much it consists of an unenumerable welter of unusual events, many of which are farcical or strange.
Moreover, my experience is that unusual but manageable individual risks, coincide far more often than seems plausible to suppose beforehand.
Employers also often have completely unreasonable ideas about how long someone can remain actively available on standby, or at what level they will perform after unreasonable amounts of time on standby.
Some people sleep poorly, especially when they're charging good money to fulfil a responsibility of being on standby for 16 hours following a normal working day, so that if the call comes in at 0900 Saturday they're now on their sixth shift of the week, with little sleep and 12 hours of standby since the last shift.
Managers can often have unreasonable expectations or indulge in self-serving biases about what workers' leisure time consists of, or what effect on-call constraints have on the disruption to free time, and the mental effort necessary to constantly evaluate ordinary leisure actions against the constraints.
Drinking? No. Hosting friends? No. Visiting a friend in a blackspot? No. Is your friend's house, or part of it, even in a blackspot for your mobile network? Who knows? It becomes relentless if "immediate response" is taken seriously and you're not at a fixed workstation or waiting-place throughout.
As a result, there can be a canyon between what pay and terms the worker requires (or will require once they realise the deal), and what coverage the manager is seeking to achieve for a given rate of pay.
So my advice would be not to be drawn into a deal on the terms you've mentioned.
It's usually more economical and effective for the employer to simply plan on the absence of supervisory staff for a certain minimum period of time (certainly overnight for daytime staff), and in exceptional circumstances rely on the goodwill of staff to respond out-of-hours if they are able to when called ad-hoc, and forestall any gruntling with generous ex-gratia payments and time off to recover.
For the worker too, this is the better deal, because they can continue to use their leisure time freely and prioritise their own arrangements.

What to charge? How much is it worth to you to give up the right to your time? Do you think they are willing to pay it? Supply and demand in real life.
Some of the comments reference remote versus onpremise, that matters a great deal obviously. Being at home gives you more flexibility with your time awaiting calls.
Start out at 2 or 2.5 times your normal pay at minimum for a reasonable starting point. Higher if it makes sense or if you don't really want the work.
Where you are located and the skillset involved, along with the critical nature of the work will affect the negotiation.
